# pass date from react to nodeServer and save it as Date type

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, mongoose

I have a react-native app and a Node server with mongoose. I want to save a date and time from the frontend and saving it in the backend, then fetch this date and display it according to its timezone.

The problem in the FE I have a date library that returns the date as a moment object, and a custom time component that returns the time as the string.

How do I Save them in one entity and send them to node server to be saved ??

Here is my implementation:

```
 const pt =
        startDay.locale('en').format('MMM Do YY') +
        ' ' +
        moment(pickupTime.formattedTime, ['h:mm A'])
          .locale('en')
          .format('HH:mm A');
```

the `startDay` is the moment Date object, `pickupTime.formattedTime` is the string for time (E.g. 3:30 PM)

Answer (score 0):

if you're using momentJS you have an easy way to create a new moment object with the date like this:

```js
let fullDateTime = moment(startDay);
```

and then just use the set from here https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/
to set the time of this new object before you send it to your backend